# dispatchGesture How to add more gesture without cancel gesture before?

Tags: java

```
Path pathpre = new Path();
              pathpre.moveTo(500,500);
              GestureDescription.Builder Builder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
              Builder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(pathpre,0,10,true));
              dispatchGesture(Builder.build(),null,null);
              //do something here after that add gesture
              Path path = new Path();
              path.moveTo(600,600);
              Builder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
              Builder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path,0,5000));
              dispatchGesture(Builder.build(),null,null);
```

When the first gesture is pressing, I want add more gesture without cancel 
the first gesture,